# JSONP callback fails, need help with javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm a noob at json (know a bit of jquery)....and trying to get a tiny script to work
I want to retrieve the time at a certain lat/lng
and made up this script in bits from what I've read online:

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&callback=?", 

    { 'uID': 1 }, 

    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            $("<span/>").html(item.time).html(".nowtime");
        });
    });
```

Needless to say, it doesn't work...could someone give me a hand with it and also explain what 
$("").html(item.time).html(".nowtime");
means. (I don't understand what the first  is)

Here is the json source reference: http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone

thanks

Comment: fire up firebug. where does it fail? sending the request? or in the callback?

Comment: nvm i ran it. it fails in the callback. firebug aint to great to debug in, but at least i can be reasonably assured that it's not XSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I originally thought the problem is most likely in the *same origin policy*. In order to do an AJAX request to a URL, it must be in the same domain (and port) as the page containing the Javascript code.

But after George IV's correction, I checked it out.

The `data` object returned in the callback is the JSON-evaled object, and it is not an array. Most likely, your code should've read something like:

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&callback=?", 
  { 'uID': 1 }, 
  function(data) {
    $("<span/>").html(data.time); // Or maybe with a different selector (see below)
  }
);
```

The selector is probably also wrong, You might want, for example, to put the result in a div with an id of `test`. The line containing the selector in that case should be changed to:

```
$("#test").html(data.time);
```

What this is saying is, get the object with id `test` (the hash sign (#) indicates it is an idea), and update the content with whatever `data.time` is set to.

Comment: it better be ok, it's what stackoverflow uses for its flair.

Comment: sweet! works great Sinan....it is so much simpler than what I thought the code would be. I suppose the each statement has to be used when one wishes to output multiple objects?

thanks for your help, and you too George IV

Comment: Normally, yes. You use `each` when you are looping through an array, which contains multiple objects. You could use `each` with an object (like `data` in the code above), but it is a different use-case; it goes over all of its properties, and you probably won't need that soon (if you are still using JSON for the first time!).

Answer (score 1):

The span code is creating a span element and then setting it's HTML to the returned time value.  The code looks wrong, though, as it immediately sets the HTML to ".nowtime" but never actually adds it to the DOM.  I'm guessing that the last .html('.nowtime')  really should be .addClass('.nowtime') and there should be a .appendTo(???) somewhere in there, but I'm not sure where you should be appending it.

**EDIT**:

Also, I don't think you need the each function.  It appears to be iterating over the members of the data object.  You want to just have it use the time property directly.

Example (though, you likely want it added to the DOM elsewhere):

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://ws.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&callback=?", { 'uID': 1 }, function(data) {
        $("<span/>").html(data.time).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

Note: if your the JSONP call were to return an array of objects **then** you would need to iterate through them with the each method.  I don't know enough about the service to know if there are methods that would return an array of objects.  This call doesn't, though.

Comment: We have a winner! I just ran it in firebug and the problem is in using the `each`. `i` is the key and `item` is the value in his case.

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear on what's wrong. The callback appears to be trying to get the nowtime field and put it in a control on the page. I think this:

```
$("").html
```

Should have a selector in the double quotes to tell it where the result goes.
Something like  $("#myfield")....

Comment: There's no "nowtime" property.  I'm guessing that it's a class that should be applied, but there's not enough code (markup) to tell.